How can I conditionally display content in the email tab of Contact Form 7 based on the selected option from a dropdown field?
I'm working with Contact Form 7 in WordPress and need to customize the content that appears in the email sent by wpcf7 based on the option selected in a dropdown field. Specifically, I want to include different table block in the email depending on which option the user selects from a dropdown field in form.
I am using a conditional plugin to show and hide fields based on selected value. I want to achieve the same functionality in the email tab. For example:
[group group-other-reference clear_on_hide]
    <p>
        <label>Tell us about the other reference:</label> 
        [text tell-other-reference placeholder "Specify if 'Other reference' is selected"]
    </p>
[/group]


try this plugin : https://wordpress.org/plugins/cf7-conditional-fields/
